# Angular2 Typescript "= () =>"

Tags: javascript

Easy question for someone to answer, what happens in this typescript function?

```
getTweetCount = () => this.data.totalCount;
```

data.totalCount is of type number from a service.

Comment: You're assigning a no-arg function that returns the total count to the name `getTweetCount`. Subsequently you could therefore do e.g. `count = getTweetCount()`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript (not "typescript'). It's just plain old ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getTweetCount = () => this.data.totalCount;
```

You are creating an "arrow function" that returns `this.data.totalCount`. There are lots of docs about arrow functions out there.

## More

Arrow functions are also covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Good to know, thank you.

Comment: Please note that, as it stands, this doesn't actually explain what an arrow function is. I've included clear attribution to avoid it being spam, but adding that into the answer itself would be better.